# Bibtex output is not compatible with natbib in aastex?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, aastex

I am now having a problem with package aastex. The code I use is:

```
\documentclass{aastex}
\begin{document}
\citep{2002PhDT........12A}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

When compiling with pdflatex, I get the error below:

```
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

The content of mybib.bib document is this:

```
@PHDTHESIS{2002PhDT........12A,
    author = {{An}, J.~H.},
    title = "{Astrophysics from binary-lens microlensing}",
    school = {THE OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY},
    year = 2002,
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002PhDT........12A},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

And mybib.bbl document is:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{2002PhDT........12A}
J.~H. {An}, {\em {Astrophysics from binary-lens microlensing}}.
\newblock PhD thesis, THE OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY, 2002.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I notice that the bibitem in mybib.bbl is not in the right form for \citep.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your code snippet cannot give rise to the error message you report: The error message is about the `natbib` package, but your code does not appear to load this package. Oh, and the instruction `\bibliography{mybib.bib}` should omit the`.bib` extension, i.e., it should read `\bibliography{mybib}`. What happens if you do load the `natbib` package, with the option `numbers`, and re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: @MikeRenfro -- Good catch...